# How to end typo3 realurl with .html

Tags: typo3, realurl

I'm using the realurl extension to make nice urls, only they all end with the / char. How can I let them end like a .html file?

`/path/to/page/`

Would like to have:

`/path/to/page.html`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In your realurl configuration file (usually `typo3conf/realurl_conf.php`<sup>1</sup>) there is a section `fileName`. In it there is a key `defaultToHTMLsuffixOnPrev`. Set it's value to `1`. Should look somehow like this afterwards (generated by realurl autoconfig):

```
'fileName' =>
array(
    'defaultToHTMLsuffixOnPrev' => 1, // <-- Important part
    'acceptHTMLsuffix' => 1,
    'index' =>
    array(
        'print' =>
        array(
            'keyValues' =>
            array(
                'type' => 98,
            ),
        ),
    ),
),
```

<sup>1</sup> If you used realurl autoconfiguration, the configuration file is generated to `realurl_autoconf.php`. Make sure to set the auto configuration format to plain PHP-code in the realurl-settings in the extension manager, then delete `typo3conf/realurl_autoconf.php` to trigger regeneration, and copy the regenerated file to `typo3conf/realurl_conf.php`.